# Do not show modal popup on back navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

I have a modal popup which displays on page load only on the home page. When I navigate to another page and then back to the home page, the popup shows again. I only want the popup to show once on the user's computer no matter how many times they navigate back to the home page. When the browser is closed and then reopened and the user goes onto the website again, only then can the popup show again. Is this possible without using sessions or a database?

HTML Code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="defaultModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="defaultModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="defaultModalLabel">Default Modal Title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur pellentesque neque eget diam posuere porta. Quisque ut nulla at nunc <a href="#">vehicula</a> lacinia. Proin adipiscing porta tellus, ut feugiat nibh adipiscing sit amet. In eu justo a felis faucibus ornare vel id metus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur pellentesque neque eget diam posuere porta. Quisque ut nulla at nunc <a href="#">vehicula</a> lacinia. Proin adipiscing porta tellus, ut feugiat nibh adipiscing sit amet. In eu justo a felis faucibus ornare vel id metus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#defaultModal').modal('show');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know about window.sessionStorage ??

```js
// Save data to sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

// Get saved data from sessionStorage
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');
```

You can learn about that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

You can use sessionStorage for this.

1. When the user first comes to home page=> set the sessionStorage variable and display the modal.
2. When user comes back to home page after navigating to some other pages, check for the sessionStorage, since it will still be set, don't display modal.
3. When user closes the browser (or tab) the sessionStorage is cleared and browsing the homepage again will display the modal.

So your js code will be like:

```js
$(window).load(function(){
  
  if(sessionStorage.getItem('homePageAlreadyVisited')  == null)//The first time this will be null
    {
      sessionStorage.setItem('homePageAlreadyVisited', 'foobar'); //foobar can be anything. You are just concerned about checking whether 'homePageAlreadyVisited' key has some value or not.
      $('#defaultModal').modal('show');
    }
//now coming back to the homepage after navigating to some other pages will not execute anything as this time, if statement is false.
});
```

Comment: You must consider by sessionStorage the navigator versions grather than IE8

Comment: I am not sure if I follow you but if you are saying that the windowStorage (session or local) is only supported in IE8 or greater, then I agree. I suppose that is not a concern as modal itself would not play nice with IE versions less than 8.

Comment: Nowadays works on all navigators. Only have problems with IE version less than 8

Answer (score 0):

Maybe set a cookie the first time the user visits the site?
And only show the modal if the cookie has not been set yet.

To lose the cookie when the user closes the browser you could do this:
Set up a very short interval and renew the cookie with a short lifetime frequently.
Even though I would not recommend this strategy as it creates a whole punch of javascript execution, I think it should work.

EDIT: If it is ok for you do let the interval run less frequent, I guess you can go for it. Maybe try once every minute? Also do not forget to run the "renew"-function on every pageload!

Answer (score 0):

Without using sessions or cookies it is not possible. If you don't want to use php_sessions (or c# or whatever) you can use [this jQuery plugin](https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin) to create a session

Answer (score 0):

Make a validation for when to open the modal. Maybe by using something on the url the first time the user enter the home page.